# Unable to connect to DB server from another machine in the same private network

Tags: postgresql, linux

I was setting up a Postgresql DB using Ansible and I was able to successfully install the DB.

My problem is that the DB machine is inside a private network (10.0.0.0/16), but when I try to connect to DB I get always "Connection refused".

This is strange because I am able to ping the DB machine from another (e.g. using `ping 10.0.0.2`).

I was thinking that it was an issue with UFW but I believe that my firewall is set correctly:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/16               
5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.0.0.0/16               
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

If I try to disable UFW, nothing changes. I continue getting the same error.

This is the output for `netstat -nlt`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Currently I have only another machine at 10.0.0.3 and I have added to `listen_addresses` in DB configuration.

`listen_addresses "localhost, 10.0.0.3"`

While I have added this line to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host all all 10.0.0.0/16 md5
```

What am I doing wrong? The desired outcome is:

- be able to connect to DB machine from my other machines inside the same private network
- be able to isolate the DB machine, blocking every outside connection that is pointing directly to the server (DB machine should be available only for machines in the same private network)

Thank you all for your precious help!

Answer (score 2):

`listen_addresses` are the addresses on which the *server* listens.

If your server is 10.0.0.2, that's what should be in `listen_addresses`, not 10.0.0.3 (which I presume is the client you're accessing from). - https://dba.stackexchange.com/u/47162